# Backbone save() respond with success

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I have a properly configured Backbone Model, but when I run the `save` method like so:

```
backbone_model.save(null, {

    success: function () { console.log('ok'); },

    error : function () { console.log('not ok'); } 

});
```

I have a successful POST request sent (and Backbone `request` is triggered) to my Node instance which responds with nothing except `200 OK` like so:

```
app.post('/backbone', function (req, res) {
    res.send(); // Automatically sends 200 OK
}
```

But Backbone does not trigger the `sync` event, and the `error` callback is executed.
I've also tried returning `201 Created`, with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backbone by default expects the response to be `JSON`, so when your respond with nothing as it is not valid JSON it triggers error callback.

if you want response to be empty just say the expected type is text

```
this.model.save(null,{
 dataType:"text",
 success:function() {},
 error:function() {}
});
```